# How can I change the duration of a layout change using collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:animated?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have this (where `layout` is a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass):

```
[layout invalidateLayout];
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:YES]
```

But it seems the duration is fixed. What's the simplest way to change the duration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:YES];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

I'm not sure whether Apple uses `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` or `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` (or some other option) in these animations. But it shouldn't be hard to find out.